# How to determine which condition is false in an if statement

Tags: scala, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have an if statement like so:

```
if(a > b && b < c) && (c > d && d < e) && (e > f && f < g)
```

Is there a way to find out which specific condition in the if statement is false in Scala 2.12? For example `(c > d && d < e)` is false, or simply `(e > f)` is false.

Comment: You'd probably need to modify it to be a nested `if` with separate conditions, or some other change.

Comment: What if they're _all_ **false**? Would you want the 1st failure, or all 6 failures? (Or should that be all 11 failures?)

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes. I think this is a really good question.

Comment: Return all 11 failures yes @jwvh

Comment: The question is not coherent. He is putting parentheses for "(c > d && d < e) ", but afterwards "simply (e > f)". Could be e typo. or could be something worse.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `if`, you can use **pattern matching**.
Something like:

```
((a > b), (b < c), (c > d), (d < e), (e > f), (f < g)) match {
  case (false, false, false, false, false) => // all failed.
  case (false, false, false, false, true) => // all but last failed.
  ...
  case (true, true, true, true, true) => // all succeed.
}
```

You can tune the logic to your specific problem.

Comment: Miguel etc.  «You can tune the logic to your specific problem.», Which logic?

Comment: @VoltyDeQua Two things in particular. 1) What to do in each case. Since OP did not specified what he / she needed for each. 2) Exactly what pattern match.

Comment: 6 different comparisons. That's 64 different result combinations. _*Ouch!*_

Comment: @ Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez. my answer below could be adjusted for that purpose. Map instead of Seq - essentially a table of conditions and what-to-do's.

Answer (score 0):

```
val r = Seq(a > b && b < c, c > d && d < e, e > f && f < g)
if (!reduce(_ && _)) println(r.indexOf(false))
```

or. to find all of them

```
r.zipWithIndex.filter(!_._1).map(_._2)
```

Comment: As you've coded it, `r` has only 3 elements. The OP might want to start with the 6 value comparisons before moving on to these 3 groupings comparisons.

Comment: @jwvh, yes -  might, or might not. :)